# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for deep nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

There is a Content model that belongs to the channel and to the template. And I wanna create template with nested attributes of channel with contents.

```
class Template < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :channels_list
  has_many :contents, inverse_of: :template
  has_many :channels, inverse_of: :template
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :channels
end

class Channel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :template, inverse_of: :channels, optional: true
  belongs_to :channels_list, inverse_of: :channels, optional: true
  has_many :contents, inverse_of: :channel
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contents
end

class Content < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :template, inverse_of: :contents
  belongs_to :channel, inverse_of: :contents
end

class ChannelsList < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :channels, inverse_of: :channels_list
  has_many :notification_templates
end
```

I want something like that

```
Template.create!(
  channels_attributes: [{ contents_attributes: [{...}])
```

create model Content with template and channel. But it creates only with channel(template is nil).

Is there a pretty way to do it? Or should I first create template and then create nested?
Thanks!

Comment: try `channels_attributes: { contents_attributes: {...}}` without the `[]` ?

Comment: No. Channels should be an array because relation is has_many

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need that redundancy? It seems that

> content.template

will return 'nil', but

> content.channel.template

will return the right model, if you don't need the redundancy, try [has many through associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) or avoid that redundancy in any other way, thats the way I would do it

If redundancy is really needed (please avoid these methods), then you can set before or after saving [callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) to set the right model at the end of your transaction, or use a [transaction](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) block and set everything manually, but these two methods can be tricky to mantain, so be careful

EDIT:

As you say you really need this redundancy, you can do something as this:

```rb
template = Template.new
template.save!(channels_attributes: [{ contents_attributes:[{ template: template, ... }])
```

The transaction block is not necessary if you won´t do any other transactions

Comment: Thanks! But The the business logic is a little more complicated. Template model can also have channels through the ChannelsList model(sorry, updated original question). So Channel can have nil template. As a result I need Content that belongs to Template and Channel to be able to get all template contents

Comment: So I think the only way is saving manually in transaction block. i have no idea now :|

Comment: I updated the answer then, but the business logic seems like it misses something, I can't tell exactly why because I don't know your business context, but my original idea was about using your content as your 'has_many through' model since I saw that 'channel' can have a 'nil' template, but then your channel could have multiple 'templates' as well (or none), I personally (imo then) avoid "tri" relationships (but report tables) because it can be tricky to deal with it most of the cases, and can be confusing, but I hope it works for you!